# Does HTTP user-agent affect page accessed in practice ? Any examples?

Tags: apache, http, user-agent

I am using wget to download url that could be used on either linux/osx/windows. My question is if server behavior could be affected by user-agent string (-U) option ? According to [this MS link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms537503.aspx) ***web server can use this information to provide content that is tailored for your specific browser***. According to [Apache doc(access control section)](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/env.html) ***you can use these directives to deny access to a particular browser (User-Agent).*** So I am wondering if I need to download links with different user-agent for different OS or one download would suffice.

Is this actually done ? I tried bunch of servers but did not really see different behavior across user agents.

Answer (score -1):

There are sites that prevent scraping by returning an error response when they detect you're hitting their servers with an automation tool instead of a browser, and the user agent is one of the aspects of detecting that difference.

Other than that not much useful can be said about this, as we don't know what sites you want to target, what HTTP server they run and what code runs on top of that.